# How to bind a dictionary with an HTML <p> tag in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I know nothing about angularJS and I haven't found any good explanation on how to bind a dictionary with an html tag so that every change in the dictionary produces a change in the number inside the `<p>` tag. For example if I have multiple dictionaries inside an array (one for each player)

```
var players = [{bambu:0, clouds:0, fruits:0}, {bambu:0, clouds:0, fruits:0} , {bambu:0, clouds:0, fruits:0}]
```

I want to display the number associated with bambu in a `<p>` tag

```
<p id="player_0_bambu" class="number_of_cards"> </p>
```

I want to change it dinamically like angular does.

I tried to do a

```
while (true){
    for (var r=0; r< num_players;r++){
        for (var c=0; c< colores.length;c++){
            $("#player_"+r+"_"+colores[c]).html(players[r][colores[c]])

        }
    }
}
```

but a while true just crashes javascript, so I turned to angular but I find it difficult to understand.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why angular would be an option but judging by your description you just loop through the `players` array and use the values from the object at hand to query for `<p/>` tags.

```
var players = [{ bambu:0, clouds:0, fruits:0 },  {bambu:0, clouds:0, fruits:0 } , { bambu:0, clouds:0, fruits:0} ]

players.forEach(player => {
  Object.keys(player).forEach(key => {
    const val = player[key];

    document.querySelector(`#player_${val}_${key}`).innerHTML = val;
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem is I want to check all the time for changes in the dictionary, is that possible? I think maybe I could do it without angular, with events, but I think the neater solution is using angular.

Comment: You'd need to either setup an interval on the client side (not recommended) or websockets on the server side.